# Launchy & Full Screen Applications

Tags: windows, fullscreen, launchy

Having some annoyances with launchy while running full screen games as the keybind that I use coincides with common key presses in some games. The obvious solution would be to rebind it, but the bind is extremely convenient in all other settings & over coming muscle memory can be an even greater annoyance. Does anyone know of a way of disabling launchy while running full screen applications? Doing a few quick searches I didn't find anything other than a similar question in the sourceforge launchy help forum with no answers.

If you're wondering what my bindings are - I use ctrl+space for launchy, meta+space for quake style drop-down shell & alt-space for inner application command lines/launchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
GameProcess := `YourGameExecutableNameHere`
Process, Wait, %GameProcess%
  Process, Close, Launchy.exe
  Process, WaitClose, %GameProcess%
    Run Launchy.exe
```

Comment: Was definitely thinking about using AutoHotKey as a solution, but did not think it would be this elegant - thanks :)